# Set ttyS0 keyboard layout

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, tty, keyboard-layout, serial-console

I have a beauty of a [serial terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfnkh.jpg), but it doesn't natively support a Dvorak keymap. Is there a way to remap this with software, or at the kernel level? It's a Wyse WY-185.

Comment: Is a real full-blown `Arch` running on the machine? If so, do you have `loadkeys`?

Comment: Yes. It's running Arch, but `loadkeys dvorak` (or any other keymap, for that matter) does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done (in older systems) using **`mapchan`** (see for example [Unixware](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/man/html.1M/mapchan.1M.html)).  There are a few imitations of that which are reported to run on Linux, which you may find useful (see [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mapchan/) for instance).